# Generating random samples from the data

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, sampling

I have 506 points in the data set. I have to generate random sample from this data such as i have to select 303 points without replacement and remaining 203 points i need to select from these 303 points.

I have written the following code.

```
def generating_samples(input_data, target_data):

    selected_rows = np.random.choice(len(input_data), 303)
    replacing_rows = np.random.choice(selected_rows,203)
    selected_columns = np.random.choice(3,13,1)
    sample_data = input_data[selected_rows[:,None],selected_columns]
    target_of_sample_data = target_data[selected_rows]

    #replicating data
    replicated_sample_data = sample_data[replacing_rows]
    target_of_replicated_sample_data = target_data[replacing_rows]

    #concatenating data
    sampled_input_data = np.vstack(sample_data, replicated_sample_data)
    target_of_sample_data = target_of_sample_data.reshape(-1,1)
    target_of_replicated_sample_data = target_of_replicated_sample_data.reshape(-1,1)
    sampled_target_data = np.vstack(target_of_sample_data,target_of_replicated_sample_data)

    return sampled_input_data , sampled_target_data, selected_rows,selected_columns



def grader_samples(a,b,c,d):
        length = (len(a)==506  and len(b)==506)
        sampled = (len(a)-len(set([str(i) for i in a]))==203)
        rows_length = (len(c)==303)
        column_length= (len(d)>=3)
        assert(length and sampled and rows_length and column_length)
        return True

a,b,c,d = generating_samples(x, y)
grader_samples(a,b,c,d)
```

But am getting following error in this.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-ca772632e834> in <module>
      7     return True
      8 
----> 9 a,b,c,d = generating_samples(x, y)
     10 grader_samples(a,b,c,d)

<ipython-input-13-bcf904f160e5> in generating_samples(input_data, target_data)
     13 
     14     #replicating data
---> 15     replicated_sample_data = sample_data[replacing_rows]
     16     target_of_replicated_sample_data = target_data[replacing_rows]
     17 

IndexError: index 391 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 303
```

Comment: `replacing_rows` are row indices of `input_data`. For example it can contain row 500. `sample_data` has 303 rows, so if you try to access row 500 in `sample_data` you will get an `IndexError`

Answer (score 0):

Use :`replicated_sample_data = input_data[replacing_rows]` because the replicating sample data comes from original dataset. 
And sample data is already sampled from the original dataset , so it is a subset of our original dataset and results in out of index error

Answer (score 0):

An error occurred due to indexing and nonunique samples.
Use :

> selected_rows = np.random.choice(len(input_data), 303, replace=False)

because of the replace=False will get 303 unique sample index. Index values can be used to extract rows from input_data.
For replicating sample we can select

> replacing_rows = np.random.choice(len(selected_rows),203,replace=False)

in replacing_rows we will get a unique sample index.
Now we can select replacing samples from the sample dataset.

> replicated_sample_data = sample_data[replacing_rows]